# How to get text of Progress View in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, rcp, progress

I have an eclipse RCP application. I want to create a view, which needs to display the text from the progress view. The default text of the progress view is "No operations to display at this time". Is there a way to get this? Or can I somehow see the operations, which are currently running?

Edit: Solved this by using "Job.getJobManager().addJobListener(new JobListener(...". The JobListener was used to print the running jobs by overwriting the "running" function of the listener.

Comment: Well the progress view is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressView` which gets most of its info from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager` - but these are all **internal** classes and I don't see any usable APIs.

Comment: Any way to get the information from somewhere else, like the log files? What I want to do is measure the time certain operations take.

Comment: It depends on exactly you want to measure. For example for Eclipse Jobs the `IJobManager` returned by `Job.getJobManager();` has listeners you can use. [edit] your question and tell us exactly what you want to measure.